R and C in comparator schematic
Reading this article and looking at the schematic inherent Phase Overcurrent Detection, I don't understand the function of these circled R85, R94, C91, C92 in blue.
I did not go into detail with the schematic, but the circuit in question has two comparators (the one up for highest level and the one down for lower level) that compare the voltage of the three phases of the electric motor with a threshold set via voltage divider on the "+" terminal of the comparator (or "-" in the case of the one down).

In my opinion:

R85 is pulldown resistor to avoid floating voltage at "-" terminal and false error detection
R94 at the bottom maybe does the same thing as R85 (but this time pullup) .. so to avoid floating voltage at the "+" terminal and false error detection
CP1 and C92 are in parallel with the resistor of the divider that sets the V to compare with the input from the phases ... perhaps a low-pass filter?

What do you think?

R94 forms a voltage divider with R93 to set the voltage necessary at  the input to trigger the bottom comparator for inputs that go low. For that, the required input (from any input) must be about 1V or less.
R85 and R84 also form a voltage divider to set the trigger voltage for the upper comparator for inputs that go high. This appears to be set for an input of about 4V for any input.
Note that the triggering input is on the non-inverting input (lower device) and the inverting input (upper device).
When triggered, the final output from either event, will go low.
The capacitors are, as you surmise, filters to reject high frequencies.
